# Selenium cannot target div in iframe only on Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I have a div with a class attribute with the value `textLayer`. I'm trying to get that div.
Here is my code:

```
WebElement jsiFrame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(jsiFrame);
        WebElement docViewerElement = driver.find(By.classname("textLayer")
```

(note: this isn't exactly the code but it's more or less the functions I call)

I also have a timeout where I wait 5 seconds while requesting each element so it's not a matter of the element not existing when I query it). Selenium fails to find it, even though it's very plainly there. What's more, it only fails on Chrome, Firefox finds it without any problems.

Comment: I would try using expected condition of "frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt": https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

Comment: Try launching with --disable-features=site-per-process

Comment: You can share html so it would be more easy to find root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dynamic xpath with explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
WebElement docViewerElement = driver.find(By.classname("textLayer")
```